# How can I store an Image to Realm database?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, realm

I'm writing an iOS application using Swift 2.2 and I want to save profile picture of an account locally in a Realm database according to resize the picked image. I googled and also saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299523/how-to-put-an-image-in-a-realm-database) but not clear well. If images are small in size or less in numbers or if I have more images or large size what can be done?

another confusion is what I will use either NSData or NSString ?
my model is

```
class IndividualContact: Object {

    dynamic var photoDataString = ""
    var photoData: NSData? = nil
    dynamic var isPhotoAvailable = false
}
```

and I already picked image from gallery

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

            imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            imageView.image = pickedImage 
        }
```

now how can I store it according to resize it as (120*110 size)?

Comment: Whats you question? resize image ya store image in database

Comment: I suggest to copy the image to the "Documents" directory and store its path.

Comment: Store image directly on realm is not advised, you should just store the image on phone's document directory and store image name/path on Realm

Comment: If I am not mistaking, you can find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299523/how-to-put-an-image-in-a-realm-database).

Comment: i don't need downloading from net. I need to resize it and store it to Realm Database. Also I wanted to know  about "if I have more images or large size"

Answer (score 7):

You can not save directly image into `Realm`, convert it into `NSData` and the store it.

if your image is of type `JPEG` then use,

```
let data = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage,0.9))
```

and if your image is of `PNG` type then use,

```
let data = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage))
```

after that write you file in realm like,

```
let realm = Realm()
realm.write{
    realm.add(data)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if I dont know what type of image it is then what I will do?

Comment: you can directly give a file path or url to get the NSData

Comment: @IrtizaKhanNiloy If we want to store image we have to convert that image into a data and then we are able to store that image, so to convert image into data there are many ways like if you want to store image wich comes from url then you can use let data = NSData(contentsOfURL:NSURL(string: "your image url"))

Comment: Brother I don't need url, I need to store an image from gallery.

Comment: You can get the image using imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage: method and default image type of images which is captured using camera is JPEG so you can easilly convert it into NSData.

Comment: I did but now I failed to retrieve data from database.

Answer (score 3):

> You can't save directly `image` into Realm, convert it into `Data` and
> the store it.

Convert your `image` to `Data`

```
let data = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage,0.9))
```

Convert data to `PNG` format if any

```
let imgPNG = UIImage.imageWithData(data)
```

Convert `PNG image` to `Data`

```
let dataPNGImg = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgPNG))
```

Store your data into Realm DB...

```
  let realm = Realm()
    realm.write{
        realm.add(dataPNGImg)
    }
```

### IMPORTANT!!!

**It is not a good idea to store an image in the database. It will increase database load and processing time. You can store the image path instead of the image.**